# SSH between N number of servers

Tags: ssh, unix, ssh-keys

I have n number of servers like `c0001.test.cloud.com`, `c0002.test.cloud.com`, `c0003.test.cloud.com` and I want to do the ssh between these servers like: from Server: c0001 do the ssh to c0002 and then exit the server. Come back to c0001 do the ssh to c0003 and then exit the server.

So in this way it will execute the script without entering any input during runtime and we can have n number of servers. I have written one script :

```
str1=c0001.test.cloud.com,c0002.test.cloud.com,c0003.test.cloud.com
string="$( cut -d ',' -f 2- <<< "$str1" )"
echo "$string"
for j in $(echo $string | sed "s/,/ /g") do ssh appAccount@j done
```

But this script is not running fine. I have also checked it by passing parameters
like: `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` and `<<'ENDSSH'` but it is not working. So how we can achieve ssh between multiple servers using scripting?

Comment: Why are you doing this?  What's the goal?

Comment: After doing the ssh I need to push the data from c001 to different servers.

Comment: Since you're trying to push files, I suggest using a file transfer protocol instead like sftp or rsync.  Those are straightforward to automate as well.  You might consider pulling from the clients instead of pushing from the origin.

Comment: Earlier we were doing this manually like: ssh appAccount@serverName after this it will ask for : Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? and then by typing yes we can achieve that and this process repeats for every server. But I want to automate this process.

Comment: Why did you post [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1341903/432690) again? Are you the same author?

Comment: I was not able to add comments on that question.

Comment: Please see this: [*I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?*](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) Since the other question is downwoted and marked as duplicate, you may pretend it's not yours and not try to merge the accounts. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You’re saying
   `for j in …(values)… do ssh appAccount@j done`,
   using `j` as a shell variable. 
   But that means that you need to reference that variable
   as `$j`, e.g., `ssh "appAccount@$j"`.
2. You need a semicolon (**`;`**) or a newline
   between `ssh "appAccount@$j"` and `done`.

There are other problems
— e.g., all shell variable references should be quoted
— but the above should get you started.

Comment: Hi Scott, After adding the ; it is again asking for Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?    Earlier we were doing this manually like: ssh appAccount@serverName after this it will ask for : Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? and then by typing yes we can achieve that and this process repeats for every server. But I want to automate this process so want to write the script and execute that in loop so that it will do shh between all the machines that are present in the list.